# Getting different results while stepped in (Threading)

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, breakpoints

Firstly, if this is a question that has been asked already, don't get angry and just link me the original please, I couldn't find it. Thank you :)

Ok, so I don't really know how to explain this. When I step into my code which gets all the pixels of a bitmap and puts it into a dictionary in order. When I step into the code it all runs perfectly and completes its fast. However, when I don't put any break points in, `x` and `y` at `colour = bmpThread.GetPixel(x,y);` go out of bounds and go to 4 and I have no idea why. Why is it doing this and how do I stop it?

```
    void PixelAnalyse(int x, int y, int currentPixel)
    {
        Bitmap bmpThread = bmp;

        Color colour;

        lock (bmpThread)
        {
            colour = bmpThread.GetPixel(x, y);
            //pTemp = bmpThread.GetPixel(x, y);
        }
        //this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.Rows.Clear()));

        //Get the pixel colours
        arrayOfColours[currentPixel] = colour;

        //this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0]));W
        //this.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value++));
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        cts.Cancel();
    }

    private void analyse1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(imageSize + 1, imageSize + 1);

        for (int m = 0; m < imageSize; m++)
        {
            arrayOfColours.Add(m, Color.Black);
        }

        int y, x;
        int currentPixel = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o => PixelAnalyse(x, y, currentPixel)));
                currentPixel++;
            }
        }

        PrintToDataGraph();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're capturing the **variables**, not the current value of them; basically, you're doing this:

- queue an operation that accesses the **variable** `currentPixel`, `x` and `y` (ot the current value)
- change the value of those variables
- loop

this means that *when each operation actually happens*, the values of `currentPixel`, `x` and `y` are **not what they were when you scheduled the work**.

You can avoid this by declaring new variables at the lowest scope:

```
var a = x;
var b = y;
var c = currentPixel;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o => PixelAnalyse(a, b, c)));
```

However, it is unlikely that creating *that many* work items is an optimal approach; usually you should prefer to create a smaller number of "chunky" work items for the thread-pool.

Comment: Ah thank you, that worked perfectly. And for the chunkier work items do you mean less threads than do more work so I don't have to waste time creating threads?

Comment: @JoeRoy well, technically with the thread pool you're not really in charge of the threads anyway - when and how many it allocates isn't up to you - but yes, I'm talking about reducing overheads.